# AttributeError: module 'tfx_bsl.arrow.array_util' has no attribute 'ValueCounts'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to import a csv dataset using this:

```py
full_data_stats = tfdv.generate_statistics_from_csv(data_location='PATH.csv')
```

It's giving me

> AttributeError: module 'tfx_bsl.arrow.array_util' has no attribute 'ValueCounts' [while running 'GenerateStatistics/RunStatsGenerators/GenerateSlicedStatisticsImpl/TopKUniquesStatsGenerator/ToTopKTuples']

Comment: Make sure, you're using the same versions of both `tensorflow-data-validation==0.21.2` & `tensorflow-transform==0.21.2`. The reason is that *TFDV currently depends on Tensorflow Transform package.* I will refer you towards [Tensorflow Data Validation Issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/data-validation/issues/28#issuecomment-435732998).

Comment: I have asked a similar question on official tensor flow data validation GitHub, they have included my question into *support*. You can get more information [Why tensorflow_data_validation seems like it is not working?](https://github.com/tensorflow/data-validation/issues/121#issue-599093141)